# Applying selector on a javascript element (within an event)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Event target is either fileUpload1 or fileUpload2. How ever I am having a hard time going up 2 levels in it's ancestory tree, getting the that node N and then appying JQuery Selector on that node N.

So far I have tried followiing variations:

```
e.currentTarget.parentElement.ParentElement.$('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
```

and

```
$(event.target).parent().parent().$('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
```

Here is the main code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/Home/UploadFiles',
                autoUpload: true,
                done: function (e, data) {
                    $(event.target).parent().parent().$('.file_name').html(data.result.name);
                    $(event.target).parent().parent().$('.file_type').html(data.result.type);
                    $(event.target).parent().parent().$('.file_size').html(data.result.size);
                }
            }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $(event.target).parent().parent().$('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and the body:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Add files...</span>
            <input class="fileupload" type="file" name="filesUploader1" multiple>
        </span>
        <br />
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
                <span class="sr-only">0% complete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="file_name"></div>
        <br />
        <div class="file_type"></div>
        <br />
        <div class="file_size"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Add files...</span>
            <input class="fileupload" type="file" name="filesUploader2" multiple>
        </span>
        <br />
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
                <span class="sr-only">0% complete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="file_name"></div>
        <br />
        <div class="file_type"></div>
        <br />
        <div class="file_size"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the original question that I started with, now all I need is to restrict the event executing on all the elements, or selecting the elements that it should effect.

In debugger I see the values for e and e.ParnetElement etc, but some how cant make the whole thing work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the `container` element containing the target element and then use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find) to get the `progress-bar` elemnet

```
$(e.currentTarget).closest('.container').find('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
```

Comment: That made that part work, I tried the same with other part on Completion but it is not working :

            done: function (e, data) {
                $(e.currentTarget).closest('.container').find('.file_name').html(data.result.name);
                $(e.currentTarget).closest('.container').find('.file_type').html(data.result.type);
                $(e.currentTarget).closest('.container').find('.file_size').html(data.result.size);
            }

Comment: The progress bar progressing, but the part on "            done: function (e, data) {
                $(e.currentTarget).closest('.container').find('.file_name').html(data.result.name);
                $(e.currentTarget).closest('.container').find('.file_type').html(data.result.type);
                $(e.currentTarget).closest('.container').find('.file_size').html(data.result.size);
            }" is not working

Comment: Sorry, I think that might be also working, I need to look at the variables in the debugger. It might be a different issue, java script does not throw an exception, I might need to look at the rendered html after the event somehow.

Comment: Using $(e.currentTarget).closest('.container').find('.file_name').html(data.result.nam‌​e);  has no effect! but as soon as I change it to $('.file_name').html(data.result.nam‌​e); all the elements with file_name class change, the only problem is how to make only the one in the same container as the $(e.currentTarget) change. Can I try something similar with Javascript parentElement instead? What would be the syntax for that?

Comment: When I changed it to $(e.target).closest('.container').find('.file_name').html(data.result.name); it worked! Why some are e.target and some are e.currentTarget ?

Comment: @Arjang it depends on how the handler is registered

Answer (score 1):

Rather than chaining `parent()` together, you can use [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/).

`$(event.target).parents('.progress .progress-bar').css({ ... });`